# opener.document() won't work on CHROME

Tags: javascript

Following Script isn't working in CHROME browser, IE is Fine.

I've changed `opener.document`... to `window.opener.document`.... but same situation.
It's not closing windows and transfer data to parent page.

```
function mycoupon() {
    window.open("my_coupon3.jsp?amt=<%=pay_price2%>",
                'coupon_win',
                'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollb‌​ars=yes, resizable=no,width=780,height=540');
}

function sel_coupon(c_id, amt) {
    var tot = opener.document.joinform.Org_totalprice.value;
    tot = String(Number(tot) - Number(amt));
    opener.document.joinform.totalprice.value = tot;
    opener.document.joinform.coupon_id.value = c_id;
    opener.document.joinform.all["tot"].innerHTML = maskNum(opener.document.joinform.Org_totalprice.value) + "USD - " + maskNum(amt) + " USD &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><font color='red'>Total : " + maskNum(tot) + " USD</font></b> ";
    opener.cal_payment_money();
    self.close();
}
```

Comment: can you please be clear your question .. btw, what is `opener` ?

Comment: can you please post the part of your code where you call `window.open()` to create the new window.

Comment: i used "opener" for transaction data between windows in IE.

Comment: <script>
function mycoupon() {
 window.open("my_coupon3.jsp?amt=<%=pay_price2%>", 'coupon_win','toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes, resizable=no,width=780,height=540');
}
</script>

Comment: `document` is not a `function`, it's an `object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a global variable and assign a reference to the new window then use it in your `sel_coupon()` function.

Here's an example:

```
var new_window_handle;

function mycoupon() {
    new_window_handle = window.open("my_coupon3.jsp?amt=<%=pay_price2%>",
                'coupon_win',
                'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollb‌​ars=yes, resizable=no,width=780,height=540');
}

function sel_coupon(c_id, amt) {
    var tot = new_window_handle.opener.document.joinform.Org_totalprice.value;
    tot = String(Number(tot) - Number(amt));
    new_window_handle.opener.document.joinform.totalprice.value = tot;
    new_window_handle.opener.document.joinform.coupon_id.value = c_id;
    new_window_handle.opener.document.joinform.all["tot"].innerHTML = maskNum(new_window_handle.opener.document.joinform.Org_totalprice.value) + "USD - " + maskNum(amt) + " USD &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><font color='red'>Total : " + maskNum(tot) + " USD</font></b> ";
    new_window_handle.opener.cal_payment_money();
    self.close();
}
```

In case you're interested in the reason of this behavior, it's because IE assumes that the default `window` is the most recent one. So that's why when you run the code on IE it will try to find `opener` in the new window, but other browsers are a bit more strict (which is better in this case)

Comment: mind explaining the down-vote? That'll teach me something and help me avoid making mistakes again. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry it's my fault. mis-click. Great Thanks Adnan!

Comment: Thanks again. But it has 1 problem though. On the "my_coupon3.jsp" <a href="javascript: sel_coupon('BGG30055923', '3000')"> <span class="button confirmA"><p>USE IT</p></span></a> When clicking "USE IT" link the "my_coupon3.jsp" won't closed, and nothing happened.